# How to get excel sheet title in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-5

I want to get excel sheet title.
I have method controller like this:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;



public function importCSVEXCEl()
   {

    Excel::load('test.xls', function($reader) {
        foreach($reader as $sheet)
        {

         $temp= $sheet->getTitle();
        }
    });
}
```

after execute this method show me error

> Call to undefined method PHPExcel::getTitle()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Issue #316 discussion on Github](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/316):

> If you have only one sheet, then you don't have to loop through the
>   sheets.
>
> ```
> Excel::load(public_path().$destinationPath.'/'.$name, function($sheet)
> {
>       // reader methods
>       $sheetTitle = $sheet->getTitle();  
> });
> ```
>
> To verify the injected value in the closure is indeed a Sheet, you can dump it and see if the class is called "RowCollection".
>
> If you always want to loop through the sheets no matter what, you'll
>   have to set the import.force_sheets_collection to true.

and second suggestion from the same source:

> This is what I used and seems to work
>
> ```
>  $sheetNames = Excel::load($file)->getSheetNames();
> ```

Comment: How can change import.force_sheets_collection. witch file should I change?

Comment: @paranoid This setting is in `import` section of `excel.php` file in your Laravel `config` folder.